# Why does adding a cell image to a UITableViewCell gives a warning?

Tags: iphone, ios

cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"faxicon.png"];

Warning is: 
setImage is deprecated.

Can I use another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the image property was deprecated in iOS3.0.

try `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"faxicon.png"];` instead

Answer (score 0):

If it is deprecated then read the documentation there is already a solution.